# -bash: cd: HOME not set

Tags: server, bash, ssh

Today when I logged into my server via SSH as I have been doing for the past 6 months,. However, I now receive this error message any time I run a command that makes reference to the `$HOME` environment variable:

```
-bash: cd: HOME not set
```

For instance, running `cd` throws this error, yet `cd ~` correctly changes to my users home directory.

I have been searching Google and trying all of the different suggestions for hours and I'm stumped.

I have tried editing the `.bashrc` and `.profile` files to include `export HOME=/home/aUser`, but `echo $HOME` continues to return empty even after logging out and in.

As far as I know, I have not installed any software on this server in the past few weeks, but have been logging in every few days to check things.

I login to my server with a standard SSH connection string using a private and public key:

```
ssh -i my-server.pem aUser@my-server.ca
```

I am still fairly new to Linux, so bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `ssh` does not use the same `init` scripts when starting a session. Have you already tried editing `.bash_profile`?

Here is a similar question, that might give you some extra information:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820517/bashrc-at-ssh-login

Answer (score 0):

Use `export HOME="/home/ubuntu"` .It worked for me.

Comment: OP has already tried this.